# multiple wget -r a site simultaneously?

Tags: multithreading, wget

any command / wget with options?

For multithreaded download a site recursively and simultaneously?

Answer (score 12):

I found a decent solution.

Read original at http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/wget-multi-threaded-downloading-457375/

> ```
> wget -r -np -N [url] &
> wget -r -np -N [url] &
> wget -r -np -N [url] &
> wget -r -np -N [url] &
> ```
>
> copied as many times as you deem fitting to have as much processes
>   downloading. This isn't as elegant as a properly multithreaded app,
>   but it will get the job done with only a slight amount of over head.
>   the key here being the "-N" switch. This means transfer the file only
>   if it is newer than what's on the disk. This will (mostly) prevent
>   each process from downloading the same file a different process
>   already downloaded, but skip the file and download what some other
>   process hasn't downloaded. It uses the time stamp as a means of doing
>   this, hence the slight overhead.
>
> It works great for me and saves a lot of time. Don't have too many
>   processes as this may saturate the web site's connection and tick off
>   the owner. Keep it around a max of 4 or so. However, the number is
>   only limited by CPU and network bandwidth on both ends.

Comment: Did this work for you? I'm using it on two servers without problems so far.

Comment: I use `wget -m` for simplicity, and run a few at a time

Answer (score 4):

With the use of parallel wget utilizing the xargs switch, this solution seems so much better:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11850469/1647809

Comment: It is good only when you know all the downloadable URLs in advance. That is not the case when you want to mirror a site.

Answer (score 3):

Use `axel` to download with multi connections

```
apt-get install axel

axel http://example.com/file.zip
```

Comment: or aget http://www.enderunix.org/aget/    but these aren't recursive solutions (good for other ppl who got to this question looking for one though)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always run multiple instances of `wget`, no?

Example:

```
wget -r http://somesite.example.org/ &
wget -r http://othersite.example.net/ &
```

etc. This syntax will work in any Unix-like environment (e.g. Linux or MacOS); not sure how to do this in Windows.

Wget itself does not support multithreaded operations - at least, neither the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) nor [its website](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) has any mention of this. Anyway, since wget supports HTTP keepalive, the bottleneck is usually the bandwidth of the connection, not the number of simultaneous downloads.

Comment: @c2h2: According to the wget manpage ( http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget ) and wget docs on its website ( http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html ), there is no such option (or anything similar) - `wget` is single-threaded. Sorry.