# Linux bash output fdirectory files to a text file with xargs and add new line

Tags: linux, bash, wget, xargs

I want to generate a text file with the list of files present in the folder

```
ls | xargs echo > text.txt
```

I want to prepend the IP address to each file so that I can run parallel wget as per this post : [Parallel wget in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577615/parallel-wget-in-bash)

So my text.txt file content will have these lines :

```
123.123.123.123/file1
123.123.123.123/file2
123.123.123.123/file3
```

How can I append a string as the ls feeds xargs? (and also add line break at the end.)
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `printf` and globbing to get the filenames:

```
printf '123.123.123.123/%s\n' * >file.txt
```

Or longer approach, leverage a `for` construct with help from globbing:

```
for f in *; do echo "123.123.123.123/$f"; done >file.txt
```

Assuming no filename with newline exists.

Comment: isn't it possible to do it in a one liner?