# How to download thirteen million small files faster with wget?

Tags: http, download, wget

I have a file list total 13 million files, about 140GB.
NOTE: Need maintain directory structure. Each file is approximately 100KB-2MB.

I use the `wget -x -i file_list.txt`

this is work will, but too slow.

NOTE: all is url in file list.

My server have 100M bandwidth, should be get 10M/s speed.
but `wget -x -i file_list.txt` just give me 1M/s.

How to fix it?

Comment: Maybe the remote server is not giving you more than 1M/s? It takes two to tango.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the parallel command:

```
parallel -a websites.txt --jobs 20 'wget -x'
```

with -a to read each line from the file, --jobs to say how many to run in parallel, and wget will be suffixed by the next line from the file.

Answer (score 1):

You could start wget multiple times simultaneously with following flags:

```
wget -x -N -i file_list.txt &
wget -x -N -i file_list.txt &
wget -x -N -i file_list.txt ...
```

The N Flag stands for:

```
-N,  --timestamping              don't re-retrieve files unless newer than
```

If you still encounter problems, you could try it with -r / -np: [multiple wget -r a site simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745799/multiple-wget-r-a-site-simultaneously)

Comment: You could mix jason and my solution. Like "parallel -a websites.txt --jobs 20 'wget -x -N'"

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly increase the performance by creating multiple wget instances. You can use a for loop to do this, but if the remote server is serving at 1Mbps then you are stuck at that speed.

Checkout [Parallel wget in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577615/parallel-wget-in-bash) for more information on creating multiple downloads.